# Selenium Webdriver runtime Exception: unexpected alert "Please close other open tabs of the application and re-open this activity"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Selenium Webdriver runtime Exception: unexpected alert "Please close other open tabs of the application and re-open this activity", even though there are no other tabs open.
The Automation scripts were working fine, but recently I am getting the above exception.The Screenshot of the Alert:

[image: 1]

I tried with different versions of chrome, selenium stand alone driver, but the issue still exist. Why is this alert coming, even though the application is not open in any of the tabs or browsers other than the one execution through online?

Answer (score 0):

If this pop up is coming at some specific location every time then you can simply accept it by writing below lines :

```
WebDriver wb=new ChromeDriver();
wb.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Else if any unexpected pop up is coming ,while initializing the driver then you can use the below code :

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
String path=new GetBasePath().getPath_XML()+dir;
prefs.put("download.default_directory", path);
options.addArguments("disable-extensions");
prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
prefs.put("password_manager_enabled", false); 
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");

options.addArguments("--test-type");
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",**path to chromedriver.exe**"));
WebDriver wb= new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

My personal opinion , use both.